# python regex - identify String with more than N non-alphaNumerics

Tags: python, regex

I want to identify strings with more than 3 non-alphanumerics (except \.\- \s) in it, which counts punctuations & special characters.
I've tried with below regex but it identifies strings with "**non-alphanumerics in sequence**"

> ([^a-zA-Z0-9.-\s]){2,}

eg: abc__def is identified, ab_c_d is not identified

I want to identify any string which has more than 3 non-alphanumerics (except \.\- \s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want strings to be identified in which **at least three** (as suggested by your examples) non-alphanumerics occur, not necessarily in sequence, you can use:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9.\-\s].*){3}
```

You can simply use `{3}` because `.*` at the end will take care of the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for checking strings with more than 3 non-alphanumerics

```
import re
reg = r'.*([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\s]{4}).*'

print(re.search(reg,"!$#@abcdef"))
print(re.search(reg,"123abc"))
print(re.search(reg,"#$abc"))
print(re.search(reg,"abc____def"))
print(re.search(reg,"abc---def"))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/Bx3H/8)

`"\W"` i.e.`([^a-zA-Z0-9_])` can also be used for non-alphanumerics but that will exclude "_".